# How to make a Kotlin expression variable appear as a named interface in Java?

Tags: lambda, interface, kotlin

I have declared an "expression variable" (Sorry I am not sure how to name it) in a Kotlin class:

```
class Something {

    var onSelectionListener: (view: View, position: Int) -> Unit = {_, _ -> }

}
```

So that I can use Lambda to assign an expression to this variable. It works great when calling this class from another Kotlin class.

```
something.onSelectionListener = { ... }
```

But now I want to allow a Java class to be able to do:

```
something.setOnSelectionListener(new Something.OnSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(View view, int position) {
                //...
            }
        });
```

This is all just about **naming**. Because it can already do:

```
    something.setOnSelectionListener(new Function2<View, Integer, Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke(View view, Integer integer) {
            //....
        }
    });
```

But those `Function2`, `invoke` and `Unit` are bad for readability.

How can I change these generated names (I expect there might be some annotations that can achieve this), while preserving the effect that the call from Kotlin class can still use Lambda to assign an expression instead of creating an anonymous class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function2 is part of Kotlin generated files, and you can't change anything from there.

So there are 2 ways of dealing with this:

1. Use JDK 8 in your application. And using the same code that you make, you can call this in your Java code.

   ```
   s = Something();
   s.setOnSelectionListener((view, position) -> {
       ...
       return null;
   });
   ```
2. If you can't use JDK 8, and need to use JDK 7, the best approach is to make an anonymous class or interface. Besides, it's still simple and make it much more readable whether you're writing in Kotlin or Java.

**Example:**

Something.kt

```
class Something {

    lateinit var onSelectionListener: OnSelectionListener

    interface OnSelectionListener {

        fun onItemSelected(view: View, position: Int)
    }
}
```

SomethingJava.java

```
s = new Something();
s.setOnSelectionListener(new Something.OnSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(@NotNull View view, int position) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I cannot control whether the user is using JDK8 or not sicne I am writing a library indeed; as for declaring an interface, it will make writing in Kotlin lose the ability of accepting lambda...

Comment: @SiraLam It won't, if you declare the interface in a Java file (in your Kotlin project). Though it will have to be just `OnSelectionListener` or `SomethingOnSelectionListener`, not `Something.OnSelectionListener`.